# Is it possible to have different settings for different Queue triggers in an Azure Function App?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage-queues, queuetrigger

Below is from Azure Storage Queue documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue. It seems to me all Queue triggers in an Azure Function app get the same settings (the settings in the "queues" block) and there's no way to have different settings for different Queue triggers. Am I correct? If that is true, any recommendation on potential workarounds?

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensions": {
        "queues": {
            "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:02",
            "visibilityTimeout" : "00:00:30",
            "batchSize": 16,
            "maxDequeueCount": 5,
            "newBatchThreshold": 8,
            "messageEncoding": "base64"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah azure queue trigger uses same settings , you can't have multiple settings for your queue trigger. You can create multiple function app to handle this scenario

Comment: Thank you @RahulShukla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, in an `Azure function app`, all `queue triggers` share the same setting.

I'm afraid you can only create multiple Azure function apps and then create different settings.